# Vertically and horizontally centering a matrix bigger than margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikz-matrix

This question is a follow-up on a previous question: [positioning of a matrix bigger than margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128411)

That question dealt with positioning a `pgf` matrix that exceeded the horizontal margins of the page (although I imagine this works for floats as well?), and both answers provide a solution to the problem.

However, none of those solutions work if the matrix is bigger than the margins both horizontally *and* vertically.

How can I make sure that a matrix that is (slightly) too big for the margins is centered on the text area, both vertically *and* horizontally?

It seems to me that, out of the answers provided in the previous question, the one based on `stackengine` might be more up to the task (that's why I chose to use that one below), but this may well not be the case, and of course I'm open to all sorts of suggestions.

This is a sample document using the `stackengine` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\zerowidth[2][c]{\stackengine{0pt}{}{#2}{O}{#1}{F}{T}{L}}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\toowide
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=4em,
        text height=5em,
        minimum width=10em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\unskip}

\sbox\toowide{\box0}

\centering\zerowidth{\usebox{\toowide}}

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1ex}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

Ok, I guess there are some more details that I should have added to make this question more closely reflect the actual problem. In the actual document the chart is within a `table` which is much wider than tall, so the table is *also* inside a `landscape` environment. This new MWE reflects that, and includes the partial solution by Qrrbrbirlbel:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newenvironment{xycenter}
  {\par\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}
  {\unskip\egroup\noindent\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\hsize}{\makebox[\hsize]{\box0}}\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\caption{This is my awesome caption}
\begin{xycenter}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=3.5em,
        text height=4.5em,
        minimum width=9em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
    A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{xycenter}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The size of the matrix in this case might make it look like the caption should really not be on this page at all, but the actual chart is just a bit bigger than the page, so it's not as bad as this.

An alternative solution would be to be able to use `scale` in the `tikzpicture` options, but that's the first thing I tried and it didn't seem to change anything. If scaling were possible, then I wouldn't need to fiddle so much with trying to squeeze this into that page. I'm starting to think I should rename this question...

Comment: Do you want to place the matrix at the center of the page or at the center of the text area?

Comment: Good question. I think the center of the text area would be more appropriate.

Comment: No need for a package for your zerowidth command it is just `\makebox[0pt]{...}`

Comment: `scale` doesn’t affect nodes without `transform shape` but if you consider scaling, take a look at the `tikzscale` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also trim the bounding box such that the picture still occupies a box with nonzero width and height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the margins

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\tikzset{fit to page/.style={fit only width,fit only height},
         fit only width/.style={
                    trim left={($(current bounding box.center)-(0.5*\textwidth,0)$)},
                    trim right={($(current bounding box.center)+(0.5*\textwidth,0)$)},
          },
          fit only height/.style={
                     execute at end picture={%
                     \useasboundingbox let 
                           \p1=(current bounding box.north east),
                           \p2=(current bounding box.south west) in
                           \pgfextra{\pgfresetboundingbox}
                           (\x2,-0.5*\textheight) rectangle (\x1-(0,0.5*\textheight);
                    }
          }
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[fit to page]
 \matrix [matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=4em,
        text height=5em,
        minimum width=10em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\ 
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\        
    A & B & C & D \\        
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the updated MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the margins
\usepackage{tikz,rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}

\tikzset{fit to page/.style={fit only width,fit only height},
         fit only width/.style={
                    trim left={($(current bounding box.center)-(0.5*\textwidth,0)$)},
                    trim right={($(current bounding box.center)+(0.5*\textwidth,0)$)},
          },
          fit only height/.style={
                     execute at end picture={%
                     \useasboundingbox let 
                           \p1=(current bounding box.north east),
                           \p2=(current bounding box.south west) in
                           \pgfextra{\pgfresetboundingbox}
                           (\x2,-0.5*\textheight) rectangle (\x1-(0,0.5*\textheight);
                    }
          }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fit only width]
 \matrix [matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=4em,
        text height=5em,
        minimum width=10em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-0.5\pgflinewidth,
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D & B & C & D \\        
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{AGA}
\label{asdf}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This did it. Interestingly, the caption wouldn't show unless I typed the `tikzpicture` into the source file. If I used `input` to load it from a separate file the caption would not print.

Answer (score 3):

## TikZ/`tikzpagenodes`

With the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package, all you need is the `overlay`-`remember picture` combination, the `current page text area` (pseudo) node and `\newpage`s so that the page only has the matrix on it (the `overlay` option disables the calculation of the bounding box).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
  \matrix at (current page text area.center) [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=4em,
        text height=5em,
        minimum width=10em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## More environments

Expanding on [egreg’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128443/16595), one could add the environments `ycenter` and `xycenter`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\newenvironment{xcenter}
 {\par\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}
 {\unskip\egroup\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\box0}\par}
\newenvironment{ycenter}
 {\par\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}
 {\unskip\egroup\noindent\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{\box0}\par}
\newenvironment{xycenter}
 {\par\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup\ignorespaces}
 {\unskip\egroup\noindent\parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{\makebox[\textwidth]{\box0}}\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{xycenter}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=4em,
        text height=5em,
        minimum width=10em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{xycenter}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This does indeed work, but I've bumped into another problem: this matrix is taking the place of a table in the final document. If I put the table inside `xycenter` it fails with a `not in outer par mode` error; if I put the `xycenter` environment inside the table, it works ok as long as there is no caption. But using a caption inside the table but outside `xycenter` throws the alignment off, and including the caption in `xycenter` fails with a `You can't use \hrule here except with leaders`. I'll update the MWE to reflect these (more realistic) conflicts.

Comment: @jja Yes, you can’t put a float inside a box, it wouldn’t be able float anymore. Though, to be fair, this doesn’t look like a float anymore, just a single page. For TeX, the TikZ picture is in a box the size of the text area thus the caption (between `\end{xycenter}` and `\end{table}`) will end up just below the text area. Maybe using `\captionof` without a float would be better but the same `\hrule` leaders error comes up. Maybe it would be easier to simply make the text area as big as possible while fixing its center but I am no `geometry` expert.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In my case, percusse's answer seemed to work, but your comments may come in handy for others.

Answer (score 1):

The `stackengine` approach...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand\zerowidth[2][c]{\stackengine{0pt}{}{#2}{O}{#1}{F}{T}{L}}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\toowideANDtall
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix [
      matrix of nodes,
      nodes={
        text depth=4em,
        text height=5em,
        minimum width=10em,
        draw
      },
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    ]
  {
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\ 
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
    A & B & C & D \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\unskip}
\sbox\toowideANDtall{\box0}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
\def\stacktype{L}
\savestack{\XYZ}{\belowbaseline[.5\ht\toowideANDtall-\baselineskip]{%
  \zerowidth{\usebox{\toowideANDtall}}}}
{\centering
\belowbaseline[.5\textheight]{\smash{\XYZ}}\par
}
\end{document}
```

[image]