# threeparttable: changing indentation of table footnotes

Tags: indentation, footnotes, threeparttable

OK ladies and gentlemen,
this is a follow-up question.

Although most of my concerns have been answered in the [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130809/can-i-make-this-table-fit-in-portrait-mode), I still have some issues. I want to know if there is a way to have the same indentation for the table notes as the main table. As you can see this code is good enough to fix the main table the way I like it, yet the indentation of the table footnotes is something that I do not prefer.

The main code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{OLS results} \label{ols_results}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{4cm} cccccccc @{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Non-HMO Hospitals} 
& \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{HMO-Hospitals} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(l){6-9}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Doctors} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Non-Doctors} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Doctors} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Non-Doctors} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
 & Mean &  StDev & Mean &  StDev 
 & Mean &  StDev & Mean &  StDev \\ 
\midrule
\underline{Demographics}: &&&&&&&& \\
Age & 32.59* &  [4.00] & 31.13* &   [4.28] & 32.63* &   [4.12] & 30.69* &   [4.28] \\
Mother's Education (\%) &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} Some college &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} College graduate &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} High education &&&&&&&& \\
Father's education &&&&&&&& \\
 \hspace{0.2em} Some college &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} College graduate &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} High education &&&&&&&& \\
Insurance (\%) &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} HMO &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} Government &&&&&&&& \\
\hspace{0.2em} Indigent &&&&&&&& \\
\raggedright Placental\slash uterine rupture\slash 
   haemorrhage & 1.44 & [0.23] &&&&&& \\ 
\midrule
Observations 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{2360} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{7852} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{256} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{879}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}  
\begin{tablenotes}
\tiny
\item[a] [whatever here, this is just a test] This table is made with the use of \LaTeXe. Cristobal is a port on the Atlantic side of the Panama Canal. It is located on the western edge of Manzanillo Island and is part of the Panamanian city and province of Colon. Cristobal Colon is the Spanish translation for Christopher Columbus, the Genovese explorer for whom these places were named.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton thank you so much ! This worked fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

there are some options for formatting the notes.

to position them flush left, `\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]`.

see the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/threeparttable.pdf) for details