# How to shift a large graph to the left

Tags: graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, captions

Basically, I have a large graph, which take almost half a page. Right now, when I compile the tex file, the graph shifts to the right on the pdf. I have label and caption on this graph. How can I shift it to the left such that it looks like it is being centered? I have checked out some other posts. However, none seems to work for me.

```
\begin{center}
\centering{\includegraphics[height =375px, width = 450px]{ABC.pdf} }
\captionof{figure}{ABC}
\label{abc}
\end{center}
```

Or maybe Someone can give me a solution that can allow to begin at position on the left while having the caption centre at the middle.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth helps.

Comment: or the `xcenter` environment of [positioning of a matrix bigger than margins](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128411)

Comment: I tried using `\makebox`. It works, however because I am now using `\begin{figure}` , the graph is being put on the middle of the page, whereas before when I was using `\begin{center}`, the graph is placed at the top.

Comment: Yeah, `figure`s float, but you don't have to use that. Just keep `center`, or use a `minipage`.

Answer (score 3):

The `\hsmash` macro of the 9-11 release of the `stackengine` package makes LaTex think the image is zero width.  Thus, it has no problem centering it, because it doesn't know it falls outside of the left margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
{\centering
\hsmash{\includegraphics[height =375px, width = 450px]{ABC.pdf} }
\captionof{figure}{ABC}\label{abc}}

here is textwidth\\\rule{\textwidth}{1ex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's `\centering` supposed to do?

Comment: you don't want the `\centering` inside `center` (copied from original example) Is `\hsmash{..}` different from `\makebox[0pt]{..}` ?

Comment: @egreg oversight.  Fixed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle center environment removed... Codewise, `\hsmash` is not a `\makebox`; It is more like a `\clap` (halfway between a `\rlap` and `\llap`).  Functionally, I don't know if it acts differently from a `\makebox[0pt]`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I guess it's the same then:-) `\makebox[0pt][clr]` are left right or centred *lap depending on the second arguument, defaulting to `c`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thanks for the tip, I hadn't thought about `\makebox` when coding it.  I guess it is not good to have redundantly named capability.  Too bad you didn't chime in on this answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128411/positioning-of-a-matrix-bigger-than-margins/128521#128521) and head off the macro "at the pass."

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes, is `begin{center}\hsmash{includegraphics[..]..}\end{center}`. Is it the same as your above method ?

Comment: @user1769197 In general, `begin{center}...\end{center}` is the same as {\centering...\par}, but there are places on this website where the second method is advocated as preferable to the first, for certain special cases where the first method misbehaves.  I seem to think figures was one of those places.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it doesn't misbehave, `center` environment differs from `\centering` in that it is a display environment so adds vertical space above and below, that isn't usually wanted in a float which adds its own space

Comment: @davidCarlisle:  One might define "adds vertical space above and below" in a figure environment as "misbehaving," but I thank you for explaining it clearly for user1769197 and my benefit.

Comment: it doesn't change its behaviour in a figure it always adds vertical space

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your point... "not the best choice" or "the wrong tool for the job" would have been more apt description than "misbehaving."  I stand corrected.