# Center overfull subfloats

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

I have some plots that I want to group together into one figure as subfigures using subfloat.
I want to align them as two per row but it seems they are too big (Overfull \hbox).
Nonetheless I want them to be on one row and be centered which means they should have the same distance to the left and right border of the sheet.

The following code is a stripped down version of one of my figures and exhibits the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the resulting page, the figures are much closer to the right border than to the left.

[image: The plots are shifted into the right margin]

I don't seem to be able to move them in any way.
As you can see I tried `\centering` and I also have tried `\subfloatrow` to no avail.

Comment: Do you want to resize or just shift them? You can easily resize them to `\textwidth` using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ }` (inside the `figure` environment), IMHO it would look better that way. Do you really want to place it outside the margin?

Comment: @masu: It seems that it doesn't works. I still get overfull warning! Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: If resizing is an option, I'll submit it as answer.

Comment: I guess some resizing would be okay although my original intention was to only shift as there seems to be enough space on the page.

Answer (score 14):

Use `\makebox` to set the "official width" to zero. This will remove the `overfull \hbox` warning (because TeX now considers the images to be zero points wide) and also center the box:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\makebox[0pt]{
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This feels a bit hacky. Could it interfere with other features?

Comment: @Nobody: Well, I guess some members of this site would consider _your intent_ (figures that overlap into the margins) as "a bit hacky" :-) However, the implementation with `\makebox` isn't. It's just the standard way to tell LaTeX that we want it to not care about the horizontal oversize.

Comment: They were overlapping anyways, resizing is not (really) an option and breaking between the images disconnects the text from the images (that should be on the same height anyway). So what to do other than overlapping and at least have them centered?

Comment: @Nobody: I would do exactly this and also have done it a couple of times.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to resize or just shift them? You can easily resize them to `\textwidth` using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{ }` (inside the `figure` environment), IMHO it would look better that way.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Here's a sample code for shifting, with the use `subcaption` as Donut E. Knot mentioned in his comment, it would be better than `subfloat`. This should get you started.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newsavebox{\mybox}

\newlength{\boxwidth}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%
}{%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \setlength{\boxwidth}{\the\wd\mybox}%
    \addtolength{\boxwidth}{-\textwidth}%
    \hspace*{-0.5\boxwidth}\makebox[\the\wd\mybox][c]{%
        \usebox{\mybox}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
  \begin{myenv}
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[]
                    \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Left figure}
            \label{fig:Left}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[]
                    \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Right figure}
            \label{fig:Right}
    \end{subfigure}
  \end{myenv}
  \caption{Left and right figures side by side}
  \label{fig:Group}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: My initial intention was and is to only shift them.

Comment: @Nobody: Have you tried the answers on this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128411/positioning-of-a-matrix-bigger-than-margins

Comment: @Nobody: Just added the shifting. I've used that instead of centering because you might want shift that a bit more because of the axis label.

Answer (score 2):

A recommended solution with `subcaption`.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your document class
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \centering
    \subfigure[c]{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
                    \begin{axis}[]
                    \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Left figure}
            \label{fig:Left}
    \endsubfigure
    \qquad
    \subfigure[c]{.4\linewidth}
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
                    \begin{axis}[]
                    \end{axis}
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Right figure}
            \label{fig:Right}
    \endsubfigure
    \caption{Left and right figures side by side}
    \label{fig:Group}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot about the scale option. However, doesn't this scale down the ticks' texts either? Anyways, I did not want to resize.

Comment: @nobody nobody but  you: You can adjust my code above. It is really the recommended solution.

Comment: What do you mean by this? It is the recommended solution to resize? Or it is recommended to use subcaption? Or both?

Comment: @nobody: To use the `subcaption`. Resizing is your own decision to meet your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scale` option for `tikzpicture` as shown in code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\subfloat[]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{axis}[]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: tikzpicture scaling]

Comment: The OP never said that resize is an option (but I asked for it in a comment). ;) You should delete your answer until that time (because it is misleading).

Comment: I do not have the intention to resize but to center the graphs horizontally on the page.